# Detect QPixmap warning

Tags: python, pyqt5, warnings, python-3.7, qpixmap

I have list that contains image's path of a directory. Images are downloaded using requests having .jpg and .png extension mostly.

```
def display_image_label(self, image_path):
    self.scaled_image = QPixmap(image_path).scaled(600, 400, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
    self.image_label.setPixmap(self.scaled_image)
```

Now the issue is, few images that are .jpg doesn't load showing `QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap` because the extension should have been .png because I have checked that changing the extension from .jpg to .png loads the image. I download the images using **requests** as it is, NO file formatting done.

Now, how do I catch the warning and act on it by changing the extension of the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self.scaled_image.isNull() to check if scaling was successful or not
like:

```
if (not self.scaled_image.isNull()):
  #set it to label
else:
  #do something else if you want
```